# Android keyboard open when resize layout

Tags: android

I don't want the image to change when the keyboard is turned on, now when I open the keyboard the image shifts upwards. I don't want it to slip, I want the screen size to stay the same. I want the keyboard to be like the one in foto2 when it opens. What should I do? The image should not be corrupted

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stechomee"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRoomsUpdate"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="331dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:completionThreshold="0"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/location"
        android:hint="Güncelleyeceğiniz Odayı Seçiniz"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDeviceUpdate"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:completionThreshold="0"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/device"
        android:hint="@string/cihaz_guncelle"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Resize] [image: Don't resize]

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: post xml layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do below thing into the manifest file of the project.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: do you do by adjustPan?